# Struggling with map function in gatsby

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I am trying to organise some data into my gatsby front end, the data is being pulled through GraphQL from a Contentful CMS; the I can see the data object but I am having a hard time mapping through this:

```
   return <Layout>
    <SEO title="Page two" />
    <h1>This is our work page</h1>
    <p>Here are examples of our recent work</p>
    {data.allContentfulWorksExamplePost.edges.map(item => {console.log('item', item)})}
    <p>Welcome to page 2</p>
    <Link to="/">Go back to the homepage</Link>
  </Layout>
```

This is what the object looks like: [image]

But I am getting this error: [image]

I'm not sure why I can't map through this object.

Comment: Read the error message, it is telling you `edges` doesn't exist. You have to check how you requesting the data.

Comment: But edges is the object is it not?

Comment: Isn't edges an array with two items in it?

Comment: Did you run `gatsby clean`? Can you show the `console.log` that is printing the data in the line 45?